# Convergence of $n^{-\gamma}T$ where $T$ a hitting time for uniform rvs, can I use CLT?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X_1,X_2,\dots$ be iid uniform on $\{1,\dots,n\}$ and define $T=\inf\{k:X_k=X_r \text{ for some }r<k\}$.

The objective is to figure out when $n^{-\gamma} T$ converges weakly to some non-degenerate distribution. So $\gamma$ is a parameter that can be chosen?

My work: $P(T=k)=\frac{n-1}{n}\times \cdots \times \frac{n-(k-2)}{n} \times \frac{k-1}{n}$ so then I constructed the characteristic function. The question then reduces to the following.

As $n\rightarrow \infty$, what happens to

$$\sum_{k=2}^{n+1} \left( \prod_{j=1}^{k-2}\frac{n-j}{n} \right)\frac{k-1}{n} e^{it\frac{k}{n^\gamma}}.$$

Just plugging this into wolfram, it looks complicated. Should I recognize this, or did I do something incorrectly?

Edit: Is this actually a simple application of CLT? For any $n$, the mean and variance are finite, so this converges to some kind of normal?

Answer (score 1):

It is not hard to make the following argument rigorous.

$$\mathbb{P}(T>k)=\prod_{j=1}^{k-2} \left(1-{j\over n}\right)
\approx \prod_{j=1}^{k-2} e^{-j/n}
\approx e^{-k^2/2n}.\tag1$$ 
For any $t>0$ set $k=\lfloor \sqrt{n} t\rfloor$ and plug this into
(1)  to show that 
$$\mathbb{P}(T/\sqrt{n}>t)\to e^{-t^2/2}.$$
Thus $T/\sqrt{n}$ converges in distribution to the probability 
measure with density  $t\,e^{-t^2/2}$ on $(0,\infty)$.